# Unable to send json data using durandal JS using Knockout Binding

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, durandal

```
var   xyz=  { 
              a: ko.observable(),
              b: ko.observable(),
              c: ko.observable(),   
              d: ko.observable()

           };
        function setupControlEvents()
    {
        $("#save").on("click",handleSave);                    
    }

    function handleSave()
    {

        var data = ko.toJSON(xyz);
        //alert("data to send "+data);
        //var d = serializer.serialize(data);
        url ="../save";
    http.post(url,data).then(function(){
            alert("success");
            console("save was success");
         });
```

I am able to get the data but unable to save .. when i alert the data that i am sending  i get this
data to send {"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C","d":"D","**observable**":{"**full**":true}}

i tried to serialize with durandal's serialize.serialize() but still not working ..
i think i am unable to send the data because i am getting **obserbvable** in json data so please kindly help me to solve this..

Comment: What happens when you send the data from `.toJSON`.  The `observable` key shouldn't make much of a difference

Comment: Based on http://jsbin.com/elUkigE/2/edit, I cannot duplicate your problem. If you are having the issue described, it might be coming from another part of your code. Also, what browser are you working with? You also may want to consider using a newer version of KO if you are using an older one.

Comment: What is the HTTP code that you get? @Explosion Pills But the doc here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html says it should not.

Comment: Hi all thanks for ur valuable replay i was sending json in a string format i first converted it to object deleted that __Observable__ and sent that object as a data to http.post , now i am able to save ..

Answer (score 2):

You are applying `ko.toJSON()` twice. The method `post` from the `http` plugin in Durandal is already doing it. Take a look at the method code:

```
post:function(url, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: ko.toJSON(data),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

So you only need to do this:

```
url ="../save";
http.post(url,xyz).then(function(){
        alert("success");
        console("save was success");
});
```

Comment: thank you very much sir i did the same and i was able to solve this ..but before that i deleted that __Observable__ in my json data then i was able to save

Comment: With the code of the answer you can also have observables in the data to send. The method `ko.toJSON` wil unwrap all your obsevables.

Comment: @margabit I think what he means is ho does he get rid of the observable value in the JSON.The KO doc says it will strip the observables from the object when using toJSON function but that is not happening.